# My compiled GNU GCC 9 in Solaris 10 SPARC is not working

Tags: gcc, makefile, solaris, gnu, sparc

I have successfully compiled GNU GCC-9.1.0 successfully into Solaris 10 SPARC edition OS on my Sun/Oracle SPARC server. 
I have had to however copy the static library files of libgmp.so, libmfr.so and libmpc.so into the following directories created during the 'gmake' process
gcc-9.1.0/host-sparc-sun-solaris2.10/gcc
gcc-9.1.0/host-sparc-sun-solaris2.10/prev-gcc

I now have a problem when I try to configure using the './configure' command any tarball archive containing C code source files. When I type in './configure' I get an error message saying 'C Compiler does not work, see config.log file for details' . I have uploaded the relevant config.log file generated into the following URL. It mentions that a static library file named 'libmpc.so.3 is missing, however the library file is present within /usr/local/lib directory. How do I resolve this situation. I shall appreciate any help given to me

```
configure:2912: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/9.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: sparc-sun-solaris2.10
Configured with: ./configure --enable-obsolete --with-gmp-lib=/usr/local/lib --with-mpfr-lib=/usr/local/lib --with-mpc-lib=/usr/local/lib
...[snip]...
configure:2975: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
ld.so.1: cc1: fatal: libmpc.so.3: open failed: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1
compilation terminated.
configure:2978: $? = 1
configure:3016: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3023: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

(full config.log is at http://tab140.freewebspace.com/config-gcc9.txt)

Comment: *It mentions that a static library file named `libmpc.so.3`*  That makes no sense.  `libmpc.so.3` is supposed to be a **shared object** and not a "static library".

Comment: Ah yes. my mistake. thanks Andrew :)

Answer (score 3):

`cc1` (the compiler proper executable) depends on the dynamic `libmpc.so.3` library.

See

```
ldd `gcc --print-file-name cc1`
```

It should show you that mpc and other libraries are not found. This is because `/usr/local/lib` is not on your runtime shared library path, and you are responsible for making sure it is.
One option is to temporarily put it there: try

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ldd `gcc --print-file-name cc1`
```

If "not found" messages are gone in the second output, you can prefix all your commands involving invocations of `gcc` (such as `./configure`, `gmake`, etc.) with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Alternatively, you can `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but that still will work only for the current shell session. To make the changes permanent you can add the export command to your profile (e.g. `~/.bashrc` file for bash, I don't know what shell you are using).

---

GCC has an [installation manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) that documents the `--with-mpc-lib` option among others:

```
'--with-gmp=PATHNAME'
'--with-gmp-include=PATHNAME'
'--with-gmp-lib=PATHNAME'
'--with-mpfr=PATHNAME'
'--with-mpfr-include=PATHNAME'
'--with-mpfr-lib=PATHNAME'
'--with-mpc=PATHNAME'
'--with-mpc-include=PATHNAME'
'--with-mpc-lib=PATHNAME'
     If you want to build GCC but do not have the GMP library, the MPFR
     library and/or the MPC library installed in a standard location and
     do not have their sources present in the GCC source tree then you
     can explicitly specify the directory where they are installed
     ('--with-gmp=GMPINSTALLDIR', '--with-mpfr=MPFRINSTALLDIR',
     '--with-mpc=MPCINSTALLDIR').  The '--with-gmp=GMPINSTALLDIR' option
     is shorthand for '--with-gmp-lib=GMPINSTALLDIR/lib' and
     '--with-gmp-include=GMPINSTALLDIR/include'.  Likewise the
     '--with-mpfr=MPFRINSTALLDIR' option is shorthand for
     '--with-mpfr-lib=MPFRINSTALLDIR/lib' and
     '--with-mpfr-include=MPFRINSTALLDIR/include', also the
     '--with-mpc=MPCINSTALLDIR' option is shorthand for
     '--with-mpc-lib=MPCINSTALLDIR/lib' and
     '--with-mpc-include=MPCINSTALLDIR/include'.  If these shorthand
     assumptions are not correct, you can use the explicit include and
     lib options directly.  You might also need to ensure the shared
     libraries can be found by the dynamic linker when building and
     using GCC, for example by setting the runtime shared library path
     variable ('LD_LIBRARY_PATH' on GNU/Linux and Solaris systems).
```

Comment: your command you have written doesnt work. I get the following output

Comment: output  is        '(' unexpected

Comment: @greenelephant I guess, this command substitution syntax is not supported by your shell. The backtick form is standard, try it instead (I'm going to edit the answer now).

Comment: sorry vladislav I dont know what you mean when you mention 'backtick form' I am still a n00b :(

Comment: @greenelephant That's the command substitution syntax in shell that uses backticks: `\`command\``. There is another syntax for the same thing: `$(command)` that was not recognized by your shell, if I interpreted your first comment correctly. Does the command in the answer (I have updated it) work for you now?

Comment: i will give it a try and let you know

Comment: Hi Vladislav! Ive got it to work!!! I managed to type in the ldd gcc --print-file name cc1 command and found that the cc1 executable was expecting the library files to be in /lib but as I compiled gmp, mpfr and mpc as source code from tarball file the 'gmake' program used when compiling these archives placed them into /usr/local/lib (which I was expecting gcc/cc1 to search for the library files as I had compiled gcc-9.1.0 from source. Very odd???   but in any case. I have copied the library files into directory /lib and everything is working fine!!!! :) :) :) thanks for your help :)